# Strange button behaviour in react-redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a simple counter in react-redux which I am using to learn how to use these frameworks. I am trying to implement a pair of number inputs which determine the payload of an increment/decrement action pair.

The expected result is that I enter a number into both input fields, and when I click the increment/decrement buttons, the counter goes up or down by the specified amount. What is *actually* happening is that the increment button simply *concatenates* numbers onto the end of the counter value, whereas the decrement button behaves as expected. For example:

[image: After inputting values]

The expected behaviour here is that I will press `+` and the counter will go to 5, then if I pressed `-` it would go down to -5.

[image: After pressing + twice]

Here I have pressed `+` twice. As you can see, the counter has not gone up to 10 as you might expect, but instead 5 has been concatenated onto the value in the store, rather than added.

[image: After pressing - once.]

Here I have pressed `-` once. The leading zero has disappeared, and the number has gone down by 10 as expected.

**The Code:**

Being Redux, it is a bit boilerplate-y, but here is my code:

**src/App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {increment, decrement} from './actions/counterActions';

function App() {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <input type = "number" id = "incrementAmount"></input>
      <br />
      <input type = "number" id = "decrementAmount"></input>
      <br />
      <button onClick = {() => dispatch(increment(document.getElementById("incrementAmount").value))}>+</button>
      <button onClick = {() => dispatch(decrement(document.getElementById("decrementAmount").value))}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import allReducers from './reducers/';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const devToolsExtension = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__();

let store = createStore(allReducers, devToolsExtension);

store.subscribe(() => console.log("State: ", store.getState()));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**src/actions/counterActions.js:**

```
export const increment = (incrementAmount) => {
    return {
      type: "INCREMENT",
      payload: incrementAmount
    };
  }
  
export const decrement = (decrementAmount) => {
    return {
      type: "DECREMENT",
      payload: decrementAmount
    };
  }
```

**src/actions/index.js:**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import counterReducer from './counterReducer'

const allReducers = combineReducers({counter: counterReducer});

export default allReducers;
```

**src/reducers/counterReducer.js:**

```
const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "INCREMENT":
        return state + action.payload;
      case "DECREMENT":
        return state - action.payload;
      default:
        console.warn("Action type not recognised: ", action.type);
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export default counterReducer;
```

So far I have tried using the Redux DevTools, which show that the state after pressing + is being treated as a string for some reason:

[image: Why is the state a string?]

But I've got no idea why!

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: The `value` attribute is a string, so you need to parse it with `parseInt()` or `Number()`. Is there a reason you're directly getting the value from the DOM node with `document.getElementById()` instead of [controlling the value](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)? See also: [Glossary of React Terms - Controlled vs Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components)

Comment: I think you are taking a big step in doing things, skipping the fundamentals leading to basic mistakes. you are using redux, a more advanced tools, but not using controlled input elements which is the base of react principles

Comment: @cbr my only reasoning is that I know of no other way - thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Comment: @buzatto I agree with you, unfortunately my job requires me to learn this stuff quickly and I only have so much time per week for personal development, so can't conceivably learn HTML -> JavaScript -> React -> Redux unless I want to be done in two years' time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert payload to number first:

```
return state + Number(action.payload);
```

Otherwise the result is a combined string.

Working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-minsky-ptcp3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. One question though, why does the decrement action work as intended?

Comment: There's no `-` operator for strings, so the string value (`action.payload`) gets coerced into a number.